# Access third_party folder with ci

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to access the `third_party` folder in codeigniter with the following code, but it keeps giving me a `404 not found error`

```
$config['theme']['url'] = trim(config_item('base_url'), '/ ') . '/application/third_party/themes/';
```

I have also tried removing `application`

```
 $config['theme']['url'] = trim(config_item('base_url'), '/ ') . '/third_party/themes/';
```

What do I need to do to access this, so I can have my theme folders and files in the third_party folder?

**BTW**

The above code is in a config file `config/template.php`

The problem is when the stylesheets are called in the folder, they get rejected and return the 404 error......

Comment: Apparently the `third_party` folder is a complete waste of time and space and should just be deleted. It's useless. You can't access it.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
<?php
    APPPATH.'third_party/myfolder/myfile.ext';
?>
```

Comment: This looks like a better option.

Answer (score 0):

(http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html):

Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file. Example:

```
 echo base_url();
```

You need to be sure to autoload the url helper 
So your line would look like:
    //in config/autoload.php
    $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

```
//In config/template.php
$config['theme']['url'] = trim(base_url(), '/ ') . '/third_party/themes/'; // must load $this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: I got this error with the first option: `Call to a member function item() on a non-object` I received another error on the second option as well.

Comment: This line is in `config/template.php` and the base url is obviously in `config/config.php`

Comment: Incase you wanted the actual URL and not the path, I've updated my answer. Make sure the url helper is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The `APPPATH` is a predefined constant defined in [`index.php`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/index.php#L234) It might be useful to create a new constant called `THIRD_PARTY_PATH`:

```
define('THIRD_PARTY_PATH', APPPATH . 'third_party');

include THIRD_PARTY_PATH . '/file.php';
```